# find pattern relationships using rest cypher

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher, neo4jrestclient

how can I find pattern relationships using rest cypher?

My query running on terminal :-

```
MATCH (n)<-[:DEPENDS_ON*]-(dependent) RETURN n.host as Host,
```

count(DISTINCT dependent) AS Dependents ORDER BY Dependents
 DESC LIMIT 1**

**output is :-**

+--------------------+
| Host  | Dependents |

+--------------------+
| "SAN" | 20         |
+--------------------+

where as equivalent query with rest :-

```
String query = "{\"query\" : \"MATCH (website)<-[rel]-(dependent) " +
                "WHERE TYPE(rel) = {rtype} RETURN website.host as Host," +
                "count(DISTINCT dependent) AS Dependents ORDER BY Dependents DESC LIMIT 1" +
                " \", \"params\" : {\"rtype\" : \"DEPENDS_ON*\"}}";
```

and output is empty(no records) !!!

Any help appreciated.

**P.S- When we dont use "*" in our query everything goes ok. IE both queries give same result**

Answer (score 1):

In the second query you are passing the relationship type as "DEPENDS_ON*" which is incorrect since the asterisk is being included.

The asterisk is for allowing arbitrary length paths for the specified relationship but is not part of the type.

Comment: Disappointing.  The * has some good meaning. Its there in both the queries and works well with cypher but not giving same result with rest to me

Comment: You may be able to achieve the same result by leaving the asterisk in the query itself, unwinding, then filtering:

    String query = "{\"query\" : \"MATCH (website)<-[rel*]-(dependent) " +
                "UNWIND rel as _rel WITH website, _rel WHERE " +
                "TYPE(_rel) = {rtype} RETURN website.host as Host, " +
                "count(DISTINCT dependent) AS Dependents " +
                "ORDER BY Dependents DESC LIMIT 1" +
                " \", \"params\" : {\"rtype\" : \"DEPENDS_ON\"}}";

Comment: Also you cannot specify relationships as parameters. Just write the query with the relationship (and star) as part of the query.